# Confluent Schema registry with Go application

Tags: java, go, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I understand that Confluent Schema Registry(CSR) uses kafka for schema storage. I am trying to integrate CSR with a golang application. My set up is as follows:
Client C connects to Server S1(go app), S1 writes to another server S2.
C -> S1->S2

I want to integrate CSR with S1 such that when C submits any write to S1, S1 will use CSR to validate the submitted data against the respective schema. If it is valid, S1 will forward data to S2. Client C does not know anything about CSR here.
Can such an integration be done? All documentation I could find was about how to use CSR for publishing data into kafka.

For such an integration, I would need a library of CSR. Using CSR as standalone application with REST APIs will not work since there will be huge network overhead if I make an API call to CSR for every write request submitted to S1. So I want to use sdk/library which already allows to cache the data from CSR standalone server, and can do validations locally.

If there is anything such in java, that will also work.

Answer (score 0):

> integrate CSR with a golang application

It's a Java-based *standalone* server. It cannot be "embedded" in Golang. You **need** to use REST to integrate with it.

> Client C does not know anything about CSR

Clients on both sides of the request (most commonly, a Kafka topic) need to be aware of the Registry in order to both serialize and deserialize the data via a stored schema. Otherwise, you can embed the schema definitions within each app, or some other remote HTTP service, and not need Kafka at all.

> there will be huge network overhead if I make an API call to CSR for every write request submitted to S1.

The Registry REST Client caches all schemas it sees, and does not make a call "every request" (at least the Java implementation included with `KafkaAvroDeserializer`).

---

Overall, sounds like you should be using OpenAPI, or gRPC. Not Confluent Schema Registry since you did not mention you wanted to use Kafka, only to validate your service-to-service requests... If you replaced those network calls with Kafka producer/consumer requests instead, **then** it would make sense to setup a kafka-based Schema Registry.